# Split single row into multiple rows using Pyspark

Tags: pyspark

| ID | Name | Desc1 | Desc2 | Desc3 | Desc4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | ABC | A | B | C | D |
| 200 | XYZ | X | Y |  |  |

I have data in the above format I am using PySpark Should I use explode to get the below output. Please provide an example

| ID | Name | Desc |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | ABC | A |
| 100 | ABC | B |
| 100 | ABC | C |
| 100 | ABC | D |
| 200 | XYZ | X |
| 200 | XYZ | Z |

```
dept = [(100,"ABC","A","B","C","D"),(200,"XYZ","X","Y","","")]
rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(dept)

df = rdd.toDF()
df.printSchema()

cols = ["ID","NAME","Desc1","Desc2","Desc3","Desc4"]
df.df.toDF(*cols0
df.printSchema()

df.select("ID","NAME",array(df.desc1,df.desc2,df.desc3.df.desc4).alias("DESC")).show()
df.select("ID","NAME",explode(array(df.desc1,df.desc2.df.desc3,df.desc4).alias("DESC"))).show()
```

I am getting null values in the DESC column.